# How to use data from array for math equations and terminal display? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

Complete beginner to C++

Having trouble using data from a primitive array in other places. Do i just call them as if they are integers in the math and display output lines? Making a simple Fahrenheit to Celsius converter program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array> 

int main() {
    //Display name of program 
    std::cout << "Farenheit to Celsius Converter"; 
    
    //Temperature array
    int temp[] = {51, 42, 46, 36, 46, 33, 47, 34, 48, 36, 46, 34, 45, 36};
    
    //Math stuff
    int temp1 = temp[1] - 32 * .5556; 
    int temp2 = temp[2] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp3 = temp[3] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp4 = temp[4] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp5 = temp[5] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp6 = temp[6] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp7 = temp[7] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp8 = temp[8] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp9 = temp[9] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp10 = temp[10] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp11 = temp[11] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp12 = temp[12] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp13 = temp[13] - 32 * .5556;
    int temp14 = temp[14] - 32 * .5556;
    
    //Display output
    std::cout << temp1"," << temp2"," << temp3"," << temp4"," << temp5"," << temp6"," << temp7"," << temp8"," << temp9"," << temp10"," << temp11"," << temp12"," << temp13"," << temp14","; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that arrray's indices start at `0`, so you should use `0` to `13` (inclusive), not `1` to `14` (inclusive).

Comment: `std::cout << temp1"," << temp2"," ...` should be `std::cout << temp1 << "," << temp2 << "," ...`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use the standard [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) algorithm to transform the array. You can then create a function or functor (like a lambda) for converting from Fahrenheit to Celcius and supply that to `std::transform`.

Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end

int main() {
    int temp[] = {51, 42, 46, 36, 46, 33, 47, 34, 48, 36, 46, 34, 45, 36};

    // a lambda for the conversion:
    auto F2C = [](int F) { return (F - 32) * 5 / 9; };

    std::transform(std::begin(temp), std::end(temp), std::begin(temp), F2C);

    for (int v : temp) std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nK3YhbGdb)

Comment: I love how this perfectly fine answer doesn't allow the OP to just copy and paste it for submitting his homework.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ use vector for an array with flexible size.

To get a good conversion use floating point numbers.

And repeated calculations should really be functions.

use range based for loops where you can, to avoid index problems

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array> 
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

double fahrenheid_to_celcius(const double t)
{
    return (t - 32.0) * .55556;
}

int main()
{
    //Display name of program 
    std::cout << "Farenheit to Celsius Converter\n";

    //Temperature array
    std::vector<double> temperatures{ 51.0, 42.0, 46.0, 36.0, 46.0, 33.0, 47.0, 34.0, 48.0, 36.0, 46.0, 34.0, 45.0, 36.0 };

    // convert temperatures one by one (using a range based for loop)
    // double& is a reference to one of the temperatures in the vector, so the value can be changed within the loop
    for (double& temperature : temperatures)
    {
        temperature = fahrenheid_to_celcius(temperature);
    }

    bool comma = false;
    for (const double& temperature : temperatures)
    {
        if (comma) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << temperature;
        comma = true;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: I recommended using the std::array, instead of the C-array:

```
const size_t tempValues = 14;
std::array<int, tempValues> temp = {51, 42, 46, 36, 46, 33, 47,
                                    34, 48, 36, 46, 34, 45, 36};
```

Second: you can operate via a for loop directly on the values. You don't have to write 14 variables:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tempValues; i++) {
  temp[i] = (temp[i]-32) * .5556;
}
```

Prining to the output goes similarly:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tempValues - 1; i++) {
  std::cout << temp[i] << ", ";
}
std::cout << temp[tempValues - 1] << std::endl;
```

Note that the loop ends with the second last value, because we do not need for the last value a comma separator.

This isn't the most elegant way, but probably the most beginner-friendly.

Comment: Use range based for loops if you can, it will avoid mistakes with indices going out of bound. And you don't have to do all that '-1' stuff.

Comment: I tried to avoid ranges her because I thought it would be rather confusing for the question opener (beginner level).
Why can be the -1 avoided?

Comment: I did not downvote. Not a big issue for me but : Range based for loops have a higher abstraction level and should imo be taught first. They model WHAT you want to do, more then HOW it is done.  So they should be even easier to learn then lower level index based techniques.  (It is just that everyone is still used to teaching "C++" bottom up).

Comment: I agree with you, this is a very good point. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: imho one should not assume what level is OP, a) at some point a beginner will turn to a non-beginner, but they won't if you never confront them with non-beginner material b) the question and answer is not only for OP. Just saying, I think the answer is good, though I also find it a bit strange that you say it isnt the most elegant, but dont say what would be the most elegant, its a bit like saying that this is the answer but it isnt the one that you should actually use

Comment: `temp[i] = -32 * .5556;` should be `temp[i] =  temp[i] -32 * .5556;` to resemble OPs code, and for Fahrenheit to Celcius is should actually be `temp[i] = (temp[i]-32) * .5556;`